# Compare two consecutive elements in an array

Tags: ruby, compare, conditional-statements

I want to create a "bubble sort" method, which means that I take two consecutive elements in an array, compare them and if the left element is greater than the right element, they should switch the position. I want to repeat it until my array is sorted in ascending order.

My code only works partially. If my array is too big nothing will happen (I have to quit ruby with CTRL + C). With arrays smaller than 5 elements my code works fine:

```
def bubbles(array)

  while array.each_cons(2).any? { |a, b| (a <=> b) >= 0 }                   

  # "true" if there are two consecutives elements where the first one 
  # is greater than the second one. I know the error must be here somehow.

    array.each_with_index.map do | number, index |
      if array[index + 1].nil?
        number
        break
      elsif number > array[index + 1]
        array[index], array[index + 1] = array[index + 1], array[index]     # Swap position!
      else
        number
      end   
    end
  end

p array
end
```

If I call my method with an array with 4 elements, it works fine:

```
 bubbles([1, 5, 8, 3])       # => [1, 3, 5, 8]
```

If I call it with a bigger array, it doesn't work:

```
 bubbles([5, 12, 2, 512, 999, 1, 2, 323, 2, 12])   # => Nothing happens. I have to quit ruby with ctrl + c.
```

Have I somehow created an infinite loop with my while statement?

Comment: yeah, probably there is an infinite loop somewhere there. :)

Comment: `(a <=> b) >= 0` is a horrible way to write a condition.

Comment: @sawa: and it is **the** problem of this code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes. I was about to write that. And you did. This is an example of how important it is to write a clean code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your stop condition. You won't stop until you have an array where each element is **lesser** than the next. But in your long array you have duplicated elements, so the sorted elements will have adjacent elements that are **equal** to each other.

Not being too fancy with your code will make your life easier :)

```
while array.each_cons(2).any? { |a, b| a > b }
```

Comment: Too fancy? Total ugly.

Comment: @sawa: this is totally a matter of opinion. The spaceship operator is fancier than regular `>`

Comment: If it was by itself yes, but not if you have to use another operator in combination with it. It has the same smell as `if (a  == b) == true`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you determine if the array is ordered in a separate method (and don't print the array from within the method:

```
def bubbles(array)
  until ordered?(array)
    ...
  end
  array
end
```

Here's one way (among many) to define `ordered?`:

```
def ordered?(array)
  enum = array.to_enum
  loop do
    return false if enum.next > enum.peek
  end
  true
end

ordered? [1,2,3,4,5] #=> true
ordered? [1,2,4,3,4] #=> false
```

Also, your code mutates the argument it receives (`array`), which is probably undesirable. You can avoid that by working on a copy, `array.dup`.

Comment: Ah, that second line. Thanks.